# css text orientation vertical but like writing bottom up

Tags: html, css

I want to show a text with vertical orientation, but, all examples I find on the internet display the text vertically, but like it was written from up to bottom

I want exactly the opposite

[image]

I combine writing-mode with text-orientation, but I can't get the result I want

Thanks in advance,

Rafael

Comment: The properties you list have some browser compatibility issues, one alternative is just rotating the container using a transform.

Comment: Please see [ask]. We don't debug images here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try use `transform` and `rotate`

```css
.word {
  margin: 50px -30px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="word">hello world</div>
```

More about how to use this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform)

Answer (score 1):

I did it

Just used transform

```
transform: rotate(-90deg)
```

Which is the same as rotating 270deg